# Merge JS Together - Data text swap and copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 small scripts from 2 different places, trying to do 2 different things. Merging these to function at the same time is beyond my knowledge. I'm using them on a coupon website. One script swaps the text on click which works fine. Then I added the second script that copies to clipboard whatever I have in data-text. When run at the same time, only the copy to clipboard script works.

```
$("#coupon").on("click", function() {
var el = $(this);
el.text() == el.data("text-swap") 
? el.text(el.data("text-original")) 
: el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
});

$('.coupon').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var copyText = $(this).attr('data-text');

var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
textarea.textContent = copyText;
textarea.style.position = "fixed";
document.body.appendChild(textarea);
textarea.select();
document.execCommand("copy"); 
document.body.removeChild(textarea);
})
```

Comment: On of your .on("click", function()... selectors is for a class, the other is for an element.  Did you intend for them both to be an element?

Comment: I didn't built them. The first one works great based on id="coupon". I add the second one and the first stops working, but the text gets copied to the clipboard.

Comment: Please share the relevant html.  I can't tell from what you're saying what the complete picture is

Comment: `code`<a class="coupon-a" href="https://www.besthostingcodes.com/go/a2hosting/" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow">
<button class="coupon" id="coupon" data-text="SAVEFAST" data-text-swap="SAVEFAST">SEE COUPON</button>
</a>`code`

Comment: According to this, the class handler will fire when you click either the button or the link.  Is that what you want?  Did you set a breakpoint?  Try changing each click handler to use an ID selector, and have it handle whatever you want to do specifically for the element you want